# Retrieve child object value from Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the first name from a JSON database in Firebase. The structure of the database is as follows

```
users
|_Unique ID
   |_firstName
   |_lastName
   |_userEmail
   |_userID (Which I copied to the database from FirebaseAuth account creation)
```

I'm trying to display the firstName in a Welcome label. Here's how I have the view controller set up (Disclaimer, I'm a designer slowly learning how to work in XCode)

```
class HomeVC : UIViewController  {
let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

@IBOutlet weak var WelcomeLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let userID = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!

    rootRef.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEventOfType(
        .Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let firstName = snapshot.value!["firstName"] as! String
        self.WelcomeLabel.text = firstName
    })
}

}
```

I keep getting an error saying that "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Any ideas? Do I happen to have my database structured incorrectly?

Comment: It looks like your snapshot doesn't have a `firstName` value. It's easiest to see this in the debugger and by using [`snapshot.hasChild("firstName")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html#a4f8f0a5933f6a71ca7f2668b9c153f39) and [`snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("firstName")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html#ad42cd676b4f064b1daa0443d1e049cce)

Comment: Ok I see that returns a null value when I use snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("firstName"). Now I see the issue. I was thinking I had the app writing the userID from the Firebase Authorization function as the UniqueID in the user database, but I was using childByAutoID to set that value. Now I have to figure out how to change that from being an auto ID to just the regular userID.